# Square table fitting in screen

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to create a table which is square and contains of squares. The whole table must fit inside the window without scrolling. It's a bit hard to explain, here is an image what I want:

[image]

Is that possible? Until now, I have this but it is not really what I want...

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/krmax44/rs136ksc/)

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
}

td:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  margin-top: 100%;
}

td .content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

td img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="content"><img src="http://placehold.it/128"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="content"><img src="http://placehold.it/128"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="content"><img src="http://placehold.it/128"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="content"><img src="http://placehold.it/128"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="content"><img src="http://placehold.it/128"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="content"><img src="http://placehold.it/128"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="content"><img src="http://placehold.it/128"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="content"><img src="http://placehold.it/128"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="content"><img src="http://placehold.it/128"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: For one thing, you need the same number of rows and columns for it to be square.  2x2, 3x3, 4x4, etc.  https://jsfiddle.net/Steve_Wellens/rs136ksc/1/

Comment: Do you want the table to get smaller to fit to the screen, or have the columns get moved to extra rows, or both? For example if the screen is too narrow for 3 boxes, it will display 2 and push the third box to the next row.

Comment: @SteveWellens apparently, it is 3x3 in my project and in the Stack snippet, but not in the fiddle... Got to fix this...

Comment: what about when display turns from landscape to portrait ? not clear what you exxpect. a square table is of course possible and if it holds square image it is even easier, you only need to set a width example with height:100vh; http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EPEyVN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it is to fill entire height :

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

table {
  margin: auto;
  width: 100vh;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  width: 33.33%;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

/* take care of portrait orientation or ratio */

html {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

body {
  margin: auto;
}

table {
  max-width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="content"><img src="http://placehold.it/128"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="content"><img src="http://placehold.it/128"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="content"><img src="http://placehold.it/128"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="content"><img src="http://placehold.it/128"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="content"><img src="http://placehold.it/128"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="content"><img src="http://placehold.it/128"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="content"><img src="http://placehold.it/128"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="content"><img src="http://placehold.it/128"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="content"><img src="http://placehold.it/128"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

but if it comes into portrait , you might need js to find out ratio of window (landscape/portrait to overwrite style sheets rules).
the use of mediaqueries for orientation to reset width to vw units will be needed too

Comment: No, landscape will be forced anyway. Thank you very much, it is the best solution.

Comment: @krmax44 okay, actually if width becomes less than height, CSS can also handle it http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/qboygo

Answer (score 0):

This will work with some jQuery: https://jsfiddle.net/rs136ksc/4/
Changed your rows to 3 (3x3 now).

The jQuery snippet makes your table's width exactly as much as your height. The table's height is exactly the window's height. This only works every time you load the page, so if you want it to be persistent you'll have to figure out some more jQuery. Good luck!

Some of the added CSS:

```
html, body {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  overflow:hidden;
}

table {
  margin:0 auto;
  height:100%;
}
```

jQuery:

```
var cw = $('.child').width();
$('.child').css({
    'height': cw + 'px'
});
```

Comment: No problem. Consider accepting the answer and/or upvoting it.